# Can't access tensorboard, python

Tags: python, window

I can't access tensorboard (http://DESKTOP-BRLVGMD:6006). My question is very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1419688/cant-access-tensorboard-website-http-desktop-mjo3v2a6006) one which, unfortunately, has not an answer.

- More **details** about my problem:

  - Name of the folder in logs: Cats-vs-dogs-CNN
  - Name of the file log: events.out.tfevents.1558182697.DESKTOP-BRLVGMD
  - OS: Windows 10 64 bit
  - Python version: 3.7.0
  - Tensorflow version: 1.13.1 (Only CPU)

I try use Python version: 3.6.2 instead but no results.

```
C:\Users\frner\Desktop\TensorFlow\logs>tensorboard --logdir=logs\
TensorBoard 1.13.1 at http://DESKTOP-BRLVGMD:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 57, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 228, in main
    self._register_info(server)
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 274, in _register_info
    manager.write_info_file(info)
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 269, in write_info_file
    payload = "%s\n" % _info_to_string(tensorboard_info)
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 129, in _info_to_string
    for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
  File "C:\Users\frner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorboard\manager.py", line 51, in <lambda>
    (dt - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()),
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```